# Java Mapper Interface How can i Injection Controll multiple DBMS

Tags: java, spring

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: sqlSessionFactory,sqlSessionFactoryOracle

[My Bean graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxp8x.jpg)

i did try... but didn't work..

```
public interface BoardMapper {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sqlSessionFactoryOracle")
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = null;
}

                    Spring proxy ▼ Injection but... NoUniqueBean
```

Mapper Interface(Java)             < = >          Mapper.xml

Is there anything I can do without implementing Mapper Interface?

Answer (score 0):

You should not inject beans (autowire) in the interface. You should do it in the class.

You defined:

```
public interface BoardMapper...
```

Should be:

```
public class BoardMapper
```